# How to Include iOS Framework in Unity

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

just a very simple question but it's stuck on my mind for a while. I have try to figure it out on the documentation of apple developer. But still i can't fix it.

I try to export a project in unity to iOS Device. But after exporting, i got this messagess.

> TO FINISH CONFIGURING THE EXPORTED XCODE PROJECT

1. Add these frameworks:

   AddressBook.framework
     AssetsLibrary.framework
     CoreData.framework
     CoreTelephony.framework
     CoreText.framework
     Security.framework
     libc++.dylib
     libz.dylib
2. Add the following bundles and frameworks from the Google Plus
   and the Google Play Games C++ SDKs. These can be downloaded from
   https://developers.google.com/games/services.

   GoogleOpenSource.framework
     GoogleSignId.bundle
     GoogleSignId.framework
     gpg.bundle
     gpg.framework

   Note: Make sure the bundles are copied to application.  This can be
   verified under Build Phases/Copy Bundle Resources.
3. Add the '-ObjC' linker flag. To do this, select the top-level project
   object, select the 'Unity-iPhone' build target, then go to the
   Build Settings tab. Search for Other Linker Flags and add
   the '-ObjC' flag to that list.

** Note: To run in the simulator, use Unity 4.6.8 or greater.

Please help me how to include framework in unity. Thank you.